# Which Lieutenant is Renji not counting?

Tags: bleach

When Ichigo fight Renji in Season 2, after he smashes Ichigo into a wall he then says then if Ichigo was somehow able to defeated him there are 11 other Lieutenants and 13 other Captains.

Including himself Renji only seems to be counting 12 Lieutenants and 13 Captains. at first i thought he was skipping Squad 4 because most lood down on then in terms of combat ability but then why would he then include Squad 4's Captain if that was the case.

So which Lieutenant is Renji not counting and why does he exclude that Lieutenant but not their Captain?

NOTE: I am referring to the English Dub

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time the 13th Division did not have a vice captain. After Kaien Shiba's death sometime before the start of the series, the position goes a while unfilled, with the duties being covered by the two third seats of 13th division, before passing on to Rukia. Therefore there was no vice captain at the time Ichigo came to rescue Rukia.

http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/13th_Division

Comment: I always forgot that Squad 13 doesn't have a lieutenant...

Comment: Then later on there was the first division commander Kyoraku who had 2 lieutenants, and Kensei who had a Super lieutenant. Though we lost a few  by the time all of that went through, wouldnt it have been funny if he had to say 15 Vice captains and 13 captains.